# Canceling changes to an individual element in CSS

Tags: css

How do I cancel the changes to one individual element in CSS?

Example:

```
a {
   text-decoration: line-through;
   color: green;
}
```

Now I would like at the end, `a.test` to ignore all rules and be displayed in the default way.

The normal colors and decorations of a link would show up on a page without any CSS influence.

All I found was to change every property that changes the element to `initial`. Is there a universal command that would exempt `a.test` from all changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude with the `:not()` CSS pseudo selector

```
a:not(.test) {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: green;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/d17vdf35/

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps a lot specially for other elements. AS a follow-up if there are properties being changed for the entire body, adding :not(.test) or :not(a.home) doesn't help.